# How to do parity analysis of band extrema?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, computational-chemistry, solid-state-physics, wien2k

To check whether electronic transitions are allowed between valence band maximum (VBM) and conduction band minimum (CBM) as per Laporte's rule, the parity of VBM/CBM is needed to be known. [This paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s43246-021-00172-9) discusses this in the second paragraph of page no.5. I would like to know how one can find out the parity of VBM/CBM of the material using the data generated in DFT calculations.

Comment: If a particular energy eigenstate $|n,\mathbf{k}\rangle$ has definite parity, this means it is also an eigenstate of the parity operator P. Then, you can calculate the expectation value $\langle n,\mathbf{k}|P|n,\mathbf{k}\rangle$ and you'll get $+1$ for even parity and $-1$ for odd parity. But note that not all energy eigenstates need to have definite parity.

Comment: @ProfM how this could be obtained for example from a CASTEP output? Thank you.

Comment: You need the wavefunction $|n,\mathbf{k}\rangle$ from the DFT code. I believe that a good way to extract these from CASTEP is to use c2x: https://www.c2x.org.uk/

Comment: I did find this paper (@ProfM as one of its authors!) using c2x for band parity analysis: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.98.161203. Thank you Professor Monserrat your comment helped me to find this great paper by you.

Comment: Mentioned in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63015160#63015160).

Comment: @ProfM Thank you for reply. Can you please describe how to do parity analysis from WIEN2k or quantum espresso output files?

Comment: In the same paper mentioned in my question at the top, the 17th sentence on page 5 talks about the VBM and CBM having even parity. I am failing to understand this as VBM is made of Ag-d orbital (even parity due to l=2) and CBM is made of Sb-p orbital (odd parity due to l=1). Is there anything (e.g. taking into consideration n of the shell) I am missing to understand the parity of these band extrema?